# Is there a way to embed HiGlass viewer on website?

Tags: html, embed, squarespace

My group has a website hosted on Squarespace and we would like to display [this interactive HiGlass viewer](http://glass.ucsc.edu:8989/app/?config=Z9WOEV6_RSWZ2KoRhUeEVA) for a genomic contact matrix on a webpage.

The **embed function** returns null when I use this link (http://glass.ucsc.edu:8989/app/?config=Z9WOEV6_RSWZ2KoRhUeEVA) despite indicating that it has been 'successfully located'

When I input the following **HTML code**, it doesn't work:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe src="http://glass.ucsc.edu:8989/app/?config=Z9WOEV6_RSWZ2KoRhUeEVA"
                width="1280" height="1000" 
                frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried removing the config from the link and tested whether it is a secure vs. unsecure issue and neither helped.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

[Squarespace embed function response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQUjd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the Embed Block, I would suggest adding either a Code Block or, if necessary, a Markdown Block to the place on the page where you want the viewer to appear.

Then enter the following within it:

```
<div style="position:relative; width:100%; padding-bottom:110%;">
  <iframe src="http://glass.ucsc.edu:8989/app/?config=Z9WOEV6_RSWZ2KoRhUeEVA" style="position:absolute; width:100%;height:100%;">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Now, in order for it to display, two things must be true:

1. You must have setup a [custom domain](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205812378-Connecting-a-domain-to-your-Squarespace-site) and be viewing the page via that custom domain, not your [built-in ".squarespace.com" domain](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206541717-Built-in-domains). The embed will not work while logged in and viewing your site in editing-mode nor if viewing it via the built-in domain.
2. You must have [SSL disabled](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815898-Understanding-SSL-certificates) (use the "Insecure" setting). The site you are embedding does not support HTTPS, but only HTTP. Therefore, in order to avoid browsers from blocking "mixed content" (secure content with insecure content), your own site (the site that is the "parent" of the embed) must also not be viewed using HTTPS. It must be equally "insecure", so to speak, as the embedded site.